# Detect end event in async system

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm writing some backend stuff with RxJS. I need to raise some event when everything's done.

1) Architecture involve `Subject`s so `onCompleted` event never happens naturally. It may be emitted manually but to do it I need to depend on some END event which... loops the circle.

2) Architecture has `pending$` `Observable` which keeps track of pending tasks. 
Unfortunately, due to async nature of system, this state can be emptied several times so it's "emptiness" on itself can't be used as END indicator.

Here is my solution which is quite a hack because it requires explicit interval constant.

```
import {Observable, Subject} from "rx";

let pendingS = new Subject();
let pending$ = pendingS
  .startWith(new Set())
  .scan((memo, [action, op]) => {
    if (action == "+") {
      memo.add(op);
      return memo;
    } else if (action == "-") {
      memo.delete(op);
      return memo;
    } else {
      return memo;
    }
  }).share();

let pendingDone$ = pending$ // a guess that
  .debounce(2000) // if nothing happens within 2 sec window
  .filter(pending => !pending.size); // and nothing is pending => we're done

pendingDone$.subscribe(function () {
  console.log("pendingDone!");
});

setTimeout(function () {
  pendingS.onNext(["+", "op1"]);
  pendingS.onNext(["+", "op2"]);
  pendingS.onNext(["+", "op3"]);
  pendingS.onNext(["-", "op2"]);
  pendingS.onNext(["-", "op1"]);
  pendingS.onNext(["-", "op3"]);
}, 100);

setTimeout(function () {
  pendingS.onNext(["+", "op4"]);
  pendingS.onNext(["-", "op4"]);
}, 500);
```

Is there more elegant solution to this (very general) problem?

Comment: Why can't you call onComplete in the calllback/promise of your last a sync operation? What exactly is the condition for onComplete?

Comment: If you don't know when everything is done, how will the program itself know?? It is like if you listen to a click on a button in a user interface, if you don't have a `close` button (i.e. user signals the end himself), you have to listen to that click forever. Why is this a problem in your case? `Rx.Observable`s are not promises, they do not end 'naturally' in the general case, they represent a potentially infinite sequence of values. If you do `Rx.Observable.range(...)` the sequence is finite, it will complete. When you use a subject, only you can know when to complete and dispose it.

Comment: Because I don't know which is last. Some operations add more operations as the part of their job. Think of web scraper where "download" operation lead to "parse" operation which can lead to a new "download" operation (if there were links in a page) and so on. The thing is I just see no evaluable condition for onComplete for now.

Comment: >> If you don't know when everything is done, how will the program itself know?<< -- I'm trying to figure out the condition of end with this question

Comment: so that means that you don't have an oncomplete condition. My question remains, why is that a problem? why can't you keep listening for new operations continuously? I mean your computer does not disconnect from the internet, every time the browser has finished downloading a page. And anyways if that is important, then generate that `onComplete` condition. This is an architecture/design problem, not an RxJS problem. Again, the library has absolutely no way to know when the sequence that YOU control is completed.

Comment: Right, this is a design question, and RxJS is used just to illustrate the problem. You've got me wrong. I'm not saying "there is no condition", I'm saying "I can't find a condition".

Comment: If you have no signal from whoever is sending operations that it has ended its operations, just use a timeout. With RxJs, you can use `.timeout(x)`. Or complete when nothing was sent during a given interval of time (`.debounce`). Or complete when you have processed X operations (`.scan(..)`). Or whatever fits your use case. Make a choice and ask a more specific question as per how to implement your `onCompleted` condition.

Comment: Thank's. I'll consider `timeout()` and how to reformulate the question to more concrete form.

Answer (score 1):

So far I have found 3 approaches to the subj.

#### 1) "Idle timeouts"

```
// next event
let pendingDone$ = pending$
  .debounce(2000)
  .filter(pending => !pending.size);

// next + completed events
let pendingDone$ = pending$
  .filter(pending => !pending.size)
  .timeout(2000, Observable.just("done"));
```

#### 2) "Sync set, async unset"

If pending removal is suspended to the next event loop iteration, next pending tasks should come before that, removing "pending is empty" temporal condition.

```
pendingS.onNext(["+", "op"]);
// do something
setImmediate(() => 
  pendingS.onNext(["-", "op"]);
);

pendingDone$
  .filter(state => !state.size)
  .skip(1); // skip initial empty state
```

#### 3) Schedulers (?)

It's seemingly possible to achieve similar results with schedulers but that would probably be an unconventional usage so I'm not gonna dig into that direction.